# How to find the angles needed to determine the bend of an arm required to make a hand touch a target?

Tags: triangles, angle

Sorry for the confusing title, I'll do my best to describe the issue I'm having. This is for a game I'm making but I'm asking the question here because it's not a programming question - it is a math question. I have a game character that, when the left/right mouse button is clicked, their arm will reach for the mouse ([image of player arm pointing at mouse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqJfU.png)). This is simple when the mouse is out of reach as the character just needs to make their arm a straight line. This is more difficult, however, when the mouse is in a position closer to the base of the arm than the upper and lower arm's combined length ([image of player arm trying to point at a mouse position close to the player - the blue line is where the arm needs to go](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ky28.png)).

I think it's easier to understand what I need based on the sourced images. I essentially need to find the two angles from the base of the arm to the mouse position in order to create the correct bend in the player's arm.

P.S. Ignore the ridiculous legs. I haven't reworked the legs to be two parts yet so they're still really small...

Comment: hello, from my understanding do you need to find these 2 angles :1st the angle between 2 blue lines(the arms of the character) and 2nd: the angle between the chest and the lower arm? and also are the lengths of the upper and lower arms same? also i am ignoring wirth of hand

Comment: The upper arm is both the forearm and the hand, which combined makes the exact length of the lower arm (basically, the lower and upper arm are of the same length). Regarding the angles, I just need to know any of the two angles as I can figure out the third angle with any of the two angles (180 - a1 + a2).

Answer (score 1):

I think this would be classed as a "homework problem", so instead of answering, I'll just give some tips.

Basically, your problem is to find the angles of a triangle, that goes from the shoulder, to its elbow, to it's hand, and back to the shoulder again.

I would recommend:

1. Drawing this triangle on the diagram.
2. Notice you know all of the lengths in the triangle.
3. Use the cosine rule to calculate your wanted angles.

Does that help?

Comment: Definitely helps now you've made me realise I know all the lengths of the sides of the triangle. Also I'm going to leave a meta question about what a homework question is in a minute or two if you wanted to help me there too. Thanks for the assistance! EDIT: Actually, I think I understand what you mean by homework question - it's not an actual homework question but it could be presented as one. Correct?